# Como juntar vários dicionários em Python?

Tags: python, dicionário

Em algumas linguagens, é possível unir `objetos/array` em um só.

Por exemplo, em PHP, eu posso unir vários `arrays` assim:

```
$userInfo = ['name' => 'Wallace']
$jobInfo = ['job' => 'Developer']
$ageInfo = ['age' => '26']

$info = array_merge($userInfo, $jobInfo, $ageInfo)
```

Isso retornaria:

```
['name' => 'Wallace', 'job' => 'Developer', 'age' => '26']
```

E em Python? Como faço?

Se eu tenho os seguintes dicionários, como posso uni-los em um só?

```
a = {"A" : 1}
b = {"B" : 2}
c = {"C": 3}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Pensei em usar o `for` já, mas fiz a pergunta no sentido de achar uma solução mais simples do que isso.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como demonstrado nesta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1518921), pode-se usar

```
z = {}
z.update(a)
z.update(b)
z.update(c)
```

Ou algo como:

```
def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

merge_dicts(a, b, c)
```

A partir do 3.5 ([PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)) foi proposto isto

```
z = {**a, **b}
```

Comment: E eu quebrando a cabeça tentando fazer isso no Python 2.7. Ainda bem que você avisou que é a partir do 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o método `update` para atualizar um determinado dicionário já existente ou criar um novo e atualizar ele.

```
>>> a = {"A" : 1}
>>> b = {"B" : 2}
>>> c = {"C": 3}
>>> c.update(a)
>>> c.update(b)
>>> c
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Usando um novo dicionário:

```
>>> novo = {}
>>> novo.update(a)
>>> novo.update(b)
>>> novo.update(c)
>>> novo
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o [update](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm), então temos:

```
a = {"A" : 1}
b = {"B" : 2}
c = {"C": 3}
abc = {}

abc.update(a)
abc.update(b)
abc.update(c)
print(abc) # {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Visto que os dicionários não estão contidos na mesma coleção (lista, tuple etc...), acho que a melhor maneira é assim